# Separate reviews for product variations woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I've been looking for a solution for a few hours now and haven't found an answer.
My customer has an eshop using woocommerce selling protein shakes and wants to have separate reviews for each variaton (flavour in this case) of each product.
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

WP Product Review would be of help. You can review individual products and grade different details about them. Each product has a list of pros and cons, plus a general description box. There is also an option to enable user reviews and then decide if they should be taken into account when displaying the final rating of the product. A helpful plugin.

Comment: I tried it, but don't see an option to enable reviews for each variation separately... I have a product with for example 4 variations and I want users to be able to review each variation and those reviews (stars) would appear in the variations table.
This is my variations table - https://ibb.co/gnhT65
This is how the seperate reviews look like - https://ibb.co/i4zam5